# Sampling FFT for Arduino Labview

Tags: arduino, signal-processing, fft, labview

I wan to build a FFT graph for my vibration sensor using arduino and labview. By using Labview Interface with Arduino I manage to get Amplitude vs Time graph. But I wan to use the frequency analysis on labview coding to identify the harmonic of faulty frequency, I been stuck with the coding for quite sometimes, anyone here can provide me some helps? thanks alot =)

[image]

Comment: What’s wrong with the output you’re getting at the moment?

Comment: I wan to display the Peak FFT in frequency domain, how come my frequency always remain at 0Hz?

Comment: I'm not an expert in FFT but does your original signal have a DC offset, and if so does that mean that the biggest peak in the FFT is in fact at 0 Hz? Could you post images of your original time-domain waveform and of the resulting FFT graph? I'm not sure if your question is about how to do FFT analysis in general or about how to implement a known FFT technique in LabVIEW.

Comment: @nekomatic the signal i adapt is show here http://i.stack.imgur.com/cM5ci.png where my sensor is at a equilibrium state, and I wan to FFT the signal output..

Comment: Your signal has a big DC offset compared to the amplitude of the AC components, so unless I misunderstand FFT then 0 Hz is going to be the biggest peak in the FFT output. If you want the FFT of just the AC components then subtract the DC offset first. This may help: http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/C1F39233BD94F2F08625736B00593E22